# Adjusting text inside btn bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, button

I have a button:

```
<div id="cta">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg">
    Who are we?
    </a>
</div>
```

---

```
#cta {

    margin-left:35%;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
}
#cta a{
    border-radius:100px;
    border-color:#FFF;
    border-width:thick;
    background-color:#ff8900;
    font-size:1.75vw;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/elcEi
(sorry no bootstrap on codepen)

And I'd like to adjust the position of the text inside, and the height of the button (which changes with size of text).

I have messed with paddings, margins, heights, aligns, vertical-aligns, line-heights, + all these in negatives.

Any ideas?

Comment: just add padding:5px 12px; to your #cta a{} css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Also, Bootstrap has additional styles for aligning text in an element, such as text-center or text-right.

P.S. Was wondering why you surrounded the button with a div. To could just as the cta class to the button itself.